# How would you use Maclaurin Series in this question?

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

How would you solve $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}$ using MacLaurin series?

Comment: Personally, I would solve it mentally, giving $1/2$.

Comment: How about using the full Taylor development formula with the upper bound on the difference function-MacLaurin series?

Comment: In my opinion, it's a basic limit…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MacLaurin series of $\cos$ you have : $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-cos(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$